# How to plug authentication information with a URL based load test using VSTS/C#

Tags: azure-devops, jwt, azure-active-directory, load-testing, web-testing

I referred this article here [Run URL based load test VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/get-started-simple-cloud-load-test?view=vsts) which describes an easy way to create a url based load test.

I want the user authentication information to be passed to the header of the url
such that the authentication should happen by fetching a token through Active directory. I am clue less how to plug such authentication information with url based load test.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest breaking it into two parts to solve this:

1. Passing authentication information to the URL based load test. You can do this by adding the appropriate header for your test case. For e.g. if the app uses a bearer token, you can pass the bearer token in header.
   The link you shared already shows how you can add header values -

[image: adding headers]

2. Create a separate test case which has to run before the URL based load test case. In fact it could be a pre-requisite/dependency for your load test case. In this test case, just get the required token that will be later passed in as header.
   To get the token, I'm assuming you would not want any interactive flow that requires a browser and user login, since it's a test case, so you can use code similar to this - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon 
   The most important piece of code in that sample is the method to acquire token

   authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientCredential);

You will need to register a new application to represent your tests in Azure AD to get the client id/client secret (or can use one of the existing registered AD apps that have access to call the endpoint you will use in your URL based load test).